# Automapper Datatable to List

Tags: c#, datatable, automapper

i want to map my datatable to List using automapper. i tried with below code but its not working, I'm getting below error.

```
var data = GetDataTableResult();
var result = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<RollCall>(data.CreateDataReader()); 

public class RollCall
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string CreationUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTs { get; set; }
    public string LastChangeUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChangeTs { get; set; }
    public byte StatusType { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryTs { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int RollcallId { get; set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double OpeningOdo { get; set; }
    public double ClosingOdo { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

**Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
IDataReader -> IList`1
System.Data.IDataReader -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[SampleDemo.RollCall, SampleDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
Destination path:
IList`1
Source value:
System.Data.DataTableReader**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Reset mapper and Creat Map then do mapper and change IList to List:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Reset();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, RollCall>();
result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<RollCall>>(data.CreateDataReader());
```